# Docker not responding to any command, nothing in the log file...

Tags: docker

I'm completely stumped on this.

I upgraded `docker-engine` to `docker-ce` and now... docker doesn't respond to any commands.

Some things I've noticed:

`dockerd` is sitting around 30 - 40% cpu usage with no containers running.

*every* single docker command appears to hang. `docker info`, `docker ps`, nothing works.

When I stop docker through `service docker start`, it takes about 30 seconds. It never took this long before.

When I enable debug logging, this is what I'm seeing in the log:

```
root@build-server-1:/var/log/upstart# cat docker.log
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
time="2017-10-09T12:28:50.182537180-07:00" level=debug msg="Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)"
time="2017-10-09T12:28:50.183345325-07:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 2570"
DEBU[0000] containerd: read past events                  count=0
DEBU[0000] containerd: supervisor running                cpus=8 memory=15950 runtime=docker-runc runtimeArgs=[] stateDir="/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd"
DEBU[0000] containerd: grpc api on /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock
/var/run/docker.sock is up
time="2017-10-09T12:28:50.683955722-07:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: containerd health check returned error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable"
time="2017-10-09T12:28:51.183928447-07:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: containerd health check returned error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable"
time="2017-10-09T12:28:51.185264109-07:00" level=debug msg="Using default logging driver json-file"
time="2017-10-09T12:28:51.185354633-07:00" level=debug msg="Golang's threads limit set to 114120"
time="2017-10-09T12:28:51.193263733-07:00" level=debug msg="Cleaning up stale layer dir" dir=837a16dbc38386d05c5c2c70f6a5cb6f1d9ce9e4d98ca0b27fea823a87e9a95b-removing driver=aufs module=graphdriver
```

Things I've done:

I've removed `/var/lib/docker`, `/var/run/docker*`. Rebooted the system, start/stop the container service.

If I could find an error in a log file somewhere, I'd have something to work off of but I haven't seen a single error. Just nothing working.

```
root@build-server-1:/var/log/upstart# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
root@build-server-1:/var/log/upstart#
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `docker --version` and `dockerd --version`? Did you properly remove the old installation before installing `docker-ce`?

Comment: Did you resolve this?